# Slow data return in nodejs query from mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, query-optimization

I'm trying to get data from mongodb using node js v15.4.0 but unfortunately the request is taking almost 15 to 20 minutes to return just 20k documents. when i open mongodb and run same query there it return the same data in miliseconds.

**DATABSE CONNECTION FILE**

```
mongoose.connect(config.db, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  poolSize: 10
});
connect();

function connect() {
  var db = mongoose.connection;
  var self = this;
  db.on("error", console.error.bind("connection error"));
  db.once("open", function () {
    console.log("db connected");
  });
}
```

**MONGODB QUERY**

```
DataModel.statics.findById = function (id) {
  return this.findOne({ _id: id })
    .populate("items")
    .populate("dealItems")
    .populate({ path: "dealItems", populate: { path: "item" } })
    .populate("subDeals")
    .populate({ path: "subDeals", populate: { path: "items" } })
    .populate({ path: "subDeals", populate: { path: "dealItems" } })
    .populate({
      path: "subDeals",
      populate: { path: "dealItems", populate: { path: "item" } },
    })
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .exec();
};
```

it will be better if data return in 1 minutes instead of 20 - 25 minutes..

Comment: i can see 7 populate, and also nested populate. so that is the bad sign of database structure and schema, avoid lookup/joins in mongodb.

Comment: **ok i agree with this but there's one model which have 0 lookup/joins.. and it's also taking the 20 -25 mins to return data from MongoDB..**

_let's see the below example_

`UserSchema.statics.findAll = function () {
  return this.find({}).exec();
};`

there's no join/lookup/populate i'm just simply trying to all documents from MongoDB but it took almost 20 - 25 mins to return the data from db

Comment: it depends on number of documents in collection, and don't execute query without any condition, definitely it will take time when you fetch all documents. i can't predict why its taking time without knowing any details.

Comment: its almost 36k document and maybe increase in future .. 
i've a website , backend, aws server and then mongo cloud DB.. when i request a documents from website it hits the aws server where backend is deployed, then the query run in backend.. i debug the issue once the api was called it won't take time.. but when the backend calls db collention it will take approx. 20 mins to return data and sometime it returns timeout error.. 

i just tried to install MongoDB in server where backend is installed and then i get the same 36k documents it took almost 9-10 seconds..

Comment: is there any difference between in cloud MongoDB and installed MongoDB?

Comment: I don't know about servers difference, you can ask new question with details someone will help you.

Comment: if you know anyone who can help me out, so kindly can you mention them?

and by the way thanks for helping :)

Comment: i don't know anyone, I can not mention anyone, this is public community, everyone will support in his own availability, you can post question there are so many reputed members will help you. or you can ask in [mongodb developer forum](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/new/)